# Formatting in Ruby Lograge log messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am using lograge in Ruby Rails environment.
I am using the following to enable lograge in my config/initializer/lograge.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
      config.lograge.enabled = true
      config.lograge.base_controller_class = 'ActionController::API' # Yes, its API-only project
      config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
      config.log_level = :debug
end
```

When I log using

```
logger.info("PROG_NAME"){"Actual log message"}
```

The result is

```
Actual log message
{"method":"GET","path":"/entity","format":"*/*","controller":"LogController","action":"simple","status":204,"duration":0.3,"view":0.0}
```

Can I get the actual log message as a field inside the JSON ? As such, I have already set the JSON formatting config.

Like,

```
{"message": "Actual log message", "method":"GET", "path":"/entity", "format":"*/*", "controller":"LogController", "action":"simple", "status":204, "duration":0.3, "view":0.0}
```